# Orbeon forms - get dropdown's label

Tags: orbeon

example form:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/f44c7d78e5c9e76ec00df2bf9bdcf63d3b708c76

I'm trying to get dropdown label value. I was able to get label value (by attribute @label) from dynamic dropdown when 'Service performs search' is set to Yes. But when 'Service performs search' is set to No or when I use static dropdown I was unable to get label value.
[image]

Is it possible to get label value in other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a regular dropdown, you would use the `xxf:itemset()` function. That function returns XML or JSON that represents all the choices, with the selected choice marked as such. For  more on this, see the [doc on `xxf:itemset()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-controls#xxf-itemset). So you could do something like:

```
xxf:itemset(
    'my-dropdown', 
    'xml', 
    true()
)/itemset/choices/item[@selected = 'true']/value
```

But currently, `xxf:itemset()` doesn't work with XBL controls, and the Dropdowns with search are XBL controls. This is covered by request for enhancement [#768](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/768).

Comment: @m.makos, I added a +1 from OP on RFE [#768](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/768). ‑Alex